# How to determine optimum value for "preference" parameter for affinity propagation in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am working on affinity propagation from scikit learn and want to find the optimum value for preference parameter. With `preference = -50` I am getting 1600 clusters, whereas with `preference = -100` there are just 8 clusters. Is there a direct method like elbow plot in k-means to determine preference parameter?

Comment: Do you see this as a Python coding question? This may be more appropriate on [stats.SE] (the SE machine learning site).

Comment: Please provide code example, inputs and expected output. Your question is vague.

Comment: The elbow method of k-means is very vague, and by no means yields an "optimum" value. What is the optimum anyway? What is the "best" result?